# how to a add a second azure function to the solution?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I went through the following process of adding a *second* Azure function to my solution:

[image]

When attempting to run locally I get the following exception:

[image]

> HTTP could not register URL http://localhost:7071/ because TCP port
>   7071 is being used by another application. Press any to
>   continue....[10/30/2018 8:52:01 PM] Loaded custom extension
>   'BotFrameworkConfiguration' [10/30/2018 8:52:01 PM] Loaded custom
>   extension 'SendGridConfiguration' [10/30/2018 8:52:01 PM] Loaded
>   custom extension 'EventGridExtensionConfig' [10/30/2018 8:52:01 PM]
>   registered EventGrid Endpoint =
>   http://localhost:7071/admin/extensions/EventGridExtensionConfig
>   [10/30/2018 8:52:02 PM] Generating 0 job function(s) [10/30/2018
>   8:52:02 PM] Found the following functions: [10/30/2018 8:52:02 PM]
>   TranslatorFunctions.Function1.Run [10/30/2018 8:52:02 PM]
>   .Apps.Alidade.TranslatorFunctions.OnTranslateHTTPTriggered.Run
>   [10/30/2018 8:52:02 PM]
>   TranslatorFunctions.OnTranslateParameterizedHTTPTriggered.Run
>   [10/30/2018 8:52:02 PM] [10/30/2018 8:52:02 PM] Host initialized
>   (1467ms) [10/30/2018 8:52:02 PM] Host started (1505ms) [10/30/2018
>   8:52:02 PM] Job host started [10/30/2018 8:52:02 PM] The following 3
>   functions are in error: [10/30/2018 8:52:02 PM] Function1: Cannot
>   access a disposed object. [10/30/2018 8:52:02 PM]
>   OnTranslateHTTPTriggered: Cannot access a disposed object. [10/30/2018
>   8:52:02 PM] OnTranslateParameterizedHTTPTriggered: Cannot access a
>   disposed object. [10/30/2018 8:52:02 PM] [10/30/2018 8:52:02 PM]

**What am I doing wrong? How do we allow for multiple azure functions to run on the same solution?**

Comment: Can you confirm the url is not in use by other application? Also what's the prompt after you add new function? Can't see the complete info in your gif.

Comment: When the function runtime starts up - it will tell you its address in the first few lines of the console window.  It may not be the one you think it is.

Comment: Check which application is using the port 7071 in your case. Probably there is a second instance of func.exe running. You can check that easily in the Windows Task Manager. Terminate the on you do not need. You can def. have multiple functions in a function app running locally.

Answer (score 2):

The way i have resolved this is I went to file `local.settings.json` and I added the `Host` section to the file:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {},
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7073
  }
}
```

Comment: This way is ot change the default port to 7073.  You get the error information is that 7071 is using by other function app on localhost. But I don't think this is a solution to how to a add a second azure function. You could add more functions in a project and we no need to run the project more times. We just need to change the function name to test. such as http://localhost:7071/function1 or http://localhost:7071/function1

Comment: @TomSun im not sure what you mean , did you mean localhost:7071 to 7072?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake ,should be localhost:7071/function1 or function2

Comment: @TomSun how is that different than what i had initially tried? i just right clicked and added a new azure function, it puts it on the same port